# What happens to someone I blocked on Facebook in these cases?

Tags: facebook

1. If I'm tagged in a photo by someone else that hasn't blocked that person. Would the blocked person see that photo on my profile page by default?
2. If I tag someone else in a photo that the bloked person can't see on my profile page. Would that person see the photo on the tagged person's profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, once you blocked someone, he/she will not be able to see anything on your profile. If photo is posted by someone else and if person (blocked by you) would be able to see the photo (depends on audience privacy), he/she would be able to see tagged people in the photo, but your name will not be clickable as you have already blocked him/her.
2. Yes, if photo is not posted by you, he/she would be able to see that photo on other people's timeline (depends on audience privacy).

Comment: I forgot to mention in 1 that the photo I'm tagged in is posted by someone else that hasn't blocked that person, would that be true either.

Comment: @user154298 : Edited answer.

Comment: Funny you mention that "...your name will not be clickable as you have already blocked him/her" because it's happened to me a couple of times, didn't know it was because of that. hmm... it seems like a loophole to discover who's blocked you.